# Subsets and Supersets when evaluating null sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In tryin to evaluate whether the following is true am I expanding these sets correctly:

{{$\emptyset$}} = { $\emptyset$, {$\emptyset$}} therefore {$\emptyset$} $\in$ {{$\emptyset$}} $\equiv$ T

But I'm not sure if the following is equivalent due to the nature of the empty set..

{{$\emptyset$}, {$\emptyset$}} = {$\emptyset$ ,{$\emptyset$}} ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation: $\{\{\emptyset\}\} = \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\} $ is false. You have just added another element (the empty set) arbitrarily. The equation $\{\emptyset\}\in\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ is true, however it is irrelevant to the equation written before it. Just look at the one term in the set, it is exactly $\{\emptyset\}$.

The final equation is again false, because $\{\emptyset\} \neq \emptyset$. Also the first set there has a repeated term which is not allowed.